# What elementary row operation happened here?

Tags: linear-algebra

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.1732.pdf) they start a proof by claiming the following:

By elementary row operations,
$$
\left | \begin{array}{cc} A^TA & A^Tx \\ x^TA & x^Tx \end{array} \right | = \left | \begin{array}{cc} A^TA & \vdots \\ 0 & x^Tx - x^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx \end{array} \right | 
$$

Elementary row operations, as they were taught to me, are limited to row switching, addition and multiplication. What is this witchcraft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out as I asked the question.

One can string together various elementary operations if one is careful. Say we apply several operations to modify the last row of a matrix $A$ as follows
\begin{align}
a_n \leftarrow a_n & - \alpha_1 a_1
\\ a_n \leftarrow a_n & - \alpha_2 a_2
\\  \vdots 
\\ a_n \leftarrow a_n & - \alpha_k a_k
\end{align}
for some $k < n$. This is equivalent to
$$
a_n \leftarrow a_n - \sum_i\alpha_i a_i
$$
This means that adding to $a_n$ a linear combination of the rows of $A$ is an elementary row operation.

Now, above we have transformed the last row of the matrix as
$$
\left ( x^TA ~~~~ x^Tx \right ) \leftarrow \left ( x^TA ~~~~ x^Tx \right ) - x^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^T (A ~~~~ x)
$$
and 
$$
x^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^T (A ~~~~ x)
$$
is a linear combination of the preceeding rows of the matrix with coefficients
$$
x^TA(A^TA)^{-1}
$$